# URL Path is not loading in xsl-Fo

Tags: xslt, apache-fop, pdfa

we are working with PDf/A with antenna house,in xsl-fo added color profile with url local file system facing error below

1)if we dont add color profile we getting error like below

**jp.co.antenna.XfoJavaCtl.XfoException: PDF output error. (3500)
Empty Output Intent Error**

2)if we add color profile in xsl-fo error like below

**jp.co.antenna.XfoJavaCtl.XfoException:PDF output error. (3352) Load ICC Color Profile Error:**

```
   <fo:Declarations>
     <fo:color-profile src="url('xx/sRGB.icc')" color-profile-name="sRGB IEC61966-2.1" />
```

or

```
     <fo:color-profile src="url(file:///xx/sRGB.icc)" color-profile-name="sRGB IEC61966-2.1" />
   </fo:Declarations>
```

Kindly help on this ??

Comment: Have you tried with an `<fo:declarations>` (lowercase *d*)? - remind that XML and XSL-FO are case-sensitive.

Comment: thank for response finally i got result by small change

Comment: (as the problem has been solved and it was caused by a simple typo, I'm flagging this question to be closed)

Comment: @potame i had given here path as absolute path by static src="url(file:///xx/sRGB.icc) is possible to read value from properties file to append in src ..